# Django admin - autocomplete select doesn't emit "change" event

Tags: javascript, django, autocomplete, jquery-select2, admin

I have a model, `Color`, with a foreign key `mill` that I'd like to autocomplete. Furthermore, I'd like to detect when the `mill` select box changes and do something with that in Javascript. However, I can't seem to trigger any JS off the select box being changed.

I set up my admin like so:

```
# admin.py

class MillAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class ColorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ['js/jquery/jquery.min.js', 'js/admin/some-function.js',]

    autocomplete_fields = ['mill']
```

And I write some Javascript:

```
// some-function.js

console.log('loaded script');
document.addEventListener('change', (function(e) {
    console.log('detected change event somewhere')
}))
console.log('event listener added')
```

In my browser console, when I visit the Color page, I see:

```
loaded script
event listener added
```

But when I select a mill, nothing more is logged.

**Further notes**:
The autocomplete itself is working just fine -- I am able to choose the mill I want, save, etc. Furthermore, if I remove `autocomplete_fields = ['mill']` from my admin, I see that the vanilla select box does trigger the `change` event as expected:

```
loaded script
event listener added
detected change event somewhere
```

I dug around in the source code long enough to find that Django is using [Select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events), which promises to emit the change event just as if it were a normal select box. But if that is happening, something else in the page must be eating it, because I'm not seeing it. What's going on? If there's a conflict between Django and Select2, does anyone know a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: I encountered the same problem when using `autocomplete_fields`. There's no documentation and the code isn't entirely clear. Never found a solution, so I removed the `autocomplete_fields` and configured it as a Select2 widget myself, which worked fine with events. Just extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events triggered by jQuery cannot be observed by native event listeners. Select2 uses jQuery's trigger function to handle events, which doesn't fire native DOM events, but you can swap the jQuery trigger for a native DOM one as illustrated here  https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4686

Comment: This helps -- I switched to a jQuery listener and was able to at least detect the event. I still had to listen on the document instead of the select, which is weird but workable:

```
// works
$(document).change(function(e) {
 console.log('detected jQuery change event in document')
 console.log(e.target)
})

// does not work
$('select').change(function(e) {
 console.log('detected jQuery change event on a select')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours looking for a solution. It is as simple as the following:

```
document.querySelector("#id_of_your_element").onchange = element => {
    console.log(element.target.value)
}
```